# Exception coming while running angular2boot demo locally

Tags: gwt, angular

I have cloned the angular2boot demo git repo and was trying to run it locally.
The application got compiled properly without any error.
But while running the application I am getting following errors in the browser
Browser- **Google Chrome**
Browser Version-  **46.0.2490.86 (64-bit)**
OS- **CentOS 6.5**
Angular2gwt- 1.5

Please refer to the screenshot for [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqc0T.png)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you share the actual link to the repo you cloned from. Or even better why not simply create the demo from a clean maven archetype? see bellow:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=fr.lteconsulting \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=angular2-gwt.archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.6
```

To install/produces and executable fat jar

```
mvn clean install
```

To run the fat jar

```
java -jar target/<your-apps-artifactId-and-version>.jar
```

Then go to `localhost:8080`